# How can i send data to a *.php file from a submitted select form without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, forms, select, refresh

I'm making a mash-up using Google Visualizator Geomap, i want to make a Dynamic selection of filters to change everytime without any "submit" button the informations retrieved from a SQL Query.

Here is my main page source:

```
<?php 
require 'protoext.php'
?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

 google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geomap']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

   function drawMap() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Code');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addRows([
        <?php while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                echo "['$r[COD]', $r[Value]],";
        } ?>
    ]);
      var options = {};
      options['dataMode'] = 'regions';
      options['region'] = 'IT';

      var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
      var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
      geomap.draw(data, options);
   };
</script>
```

The source in the "protoext.php" seems working just fine (no errors on firebug and map output is displayed).

The main problem is with the form that sends "gender" value with POST method to "protoext.php

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="gender" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option selected>Choose</option>
        <option value="total">total</option>
        <option value="male">male</option>
        <option value="female">female</option>      
    </select>
</form>

<div id='map_canvas'></div>
</div>
```

As i said it works, but it keeps refreshing the page every time i select a new value and this is preventing me from adding some new select to the form to improve the filtering of the geomap.
I know that to prevent refreshing i have to use AJAX, and i've tried several ways but it was like nothing were sent to the protoext.php.

Any idea anyone? Thank you in advance for any reply.

EDIT

Since any AJAX call i make doesn't resolve properly i will post the other php file (protoext.php) maybe i've got a conflict between functions or just incompatibility issues.

```
<?php
$selection=$_POST["gender"];
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(!$conn) die ("Error Mysql: ".mysql_error());

$sql= "USE csv_db";
$ok = mysql_query ($sql, $conn);

if(!$ok)
    die("imposs. select DB: ".mysql_error()); 

    $sql="SELECT COD, Value
FROM view_codes  //that is the view obtained from my database
WHERE  `Age` LIKE  '15+ years '
AND  `Qualification` LIKE  'totale'
AND `Home_Town` LIKE  'totale'
AND `Gender` LIKE  '$selection'
AND  `Period` LIKE  'T2-2012'";

echo "querySQL: $sql<br>"; 

$res=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
if (!$res)
    die ("Error query" .mysql_error());
?>
```

---

EDIT-Update

I've also tried  this way but still don't work.

```
<form method="post">
        <select name="gender" onchange="this.form.submit(
       function (){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "protoext.php",            //www.gautam.com?id=..&value1=..
        success:function(data){                                        
               alert("successfully submitted");
            }
          }); 
        }
    );">
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Your url here",            //www.gautam.com?id=..&value1=..
            success:function(data){                                        
                alert("successfully submitted");
            }
          });
```

Comment: i have tried but i don't know the way to put that in my code, can you please show me the exact way to implement it using the code above?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    $.post('http://example.com', $(this).serialize(), function() {
       // Done
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried but still nothing, i keep the page getting refreshed each time i make a choice. And still i don't get what i'm doing wrong, i've placed that code in header as document.ready(), maybe is there my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

In your view file

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
          $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Your url here",            //www.gautam.com?id=..&value1=..
        success:function(data){                                        
            alert("successfully submitted");
        }
      });

  })
</script>
```

Comment: i still don't get it... i mean, i have to make this script when document.ready() or i have to place it as function as argument here: this.form.submit()?

Comment: i've tried this way but when page is loaded says successfully submitted, when i make a choice on the select form it doesn't submit anything. i'm gonna update the first topic with the code of the protoext.php maybe i wrote something wrong there.

Comment: Then give the ajax function to the event submit of button click

Comment: I'm updating the main with the code i come to but still doesn't work... can you please check it out?